# Is there any open source Asynchronous and Distributed Multi-Agent System (MAS)?

Tags: asynchronous, distributed-computing, multi-agent

For a research project, I need to create an evolutionary simulation with 100 000 agents. Thus, I am looking for a distributed and asynchronous multi-agent system (MAS).

The only project I found is no longer maintained: https://github.com/ParaPhraseAGH/erlang-mas

Do you know any open-source projects in the field?

Comment: Questions asking for a software recommendations are off-topic here. This should be asked at [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name excuse me, is about Agent-Oriented Programming Framework (Like Oriented Object Programming framework). If you don't mind I keep it here :)

Comment: You might not mind, but it's [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here: Item 4: "*Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic*"

Comment: I don't think that asking if something exists, which can give several things as a response, is the same as asking for recommending one of them.

Answer (score 1):

There are many asynchronous Multi-Agent System platforms and many of them are open source too.

To tell some, I am using as criteria the most popular platforms according to a survey done by [Kalliopi Kravari and Nick Bassiliades (2015)](http://jasss.soc.surrey.ac.uk/18/1/11.html.bak):

- JADE
- Jadex
- Jason

The survey also classifies JACK and NetLogo among the most popular platforms. Although they are also asynchronous they are not open source.

Comment: Actually, I am not aware of any platform which is synchronous.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find off-site resources are off-topic here. Answering them is not beneficial, as it encourages other off-topic posts. You can find information about what is (and isn't) on topic here in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: @KenWhite you probably did not read my comment in the question, in which I am saying that asking for the existence is not asking for a recommendation.

Comment: I read what you wrote, which are recommendations for off-site resources. If the question is asking for off-site resources, answers of any sort to that question are not useful. If the question is not appropriate for this site, don't answer it. Your comment on the question doesn't change anything. Asking if something exists is not an on-topic question here, because an answer would have to identify it, which qualifies as a request to *recommend or find* an off-site resource. The exception to that would be if you answered *Yes, it exists* with no additional information added , which has no value.

Comment: Ok. I've just realise that many questions like this, even being relevant and well voted, were closed because of this reason.

Comment: You can find the site guidelines in the [help/on-topic], which specifically addresses this type of post. I linked it previously, but it seems you missed it. :-)